# How to show an array of images using URLs in a webview?

Tags: xml, arrays, string, image, url

Okay, A little background information first :

I have a ton of URLs(200+) each containing a jpeg or some type of image, I want an app where user can select the images from a listview and open up the "imageShower" activity which will have a next, previous and refresh button and ofcourse a webview to show the images.

Now I don't have any problem with :
Creating listview, sending index position as intent...
Any of the buttons.

What I want to know is exactly how do I form this array of URLs ?

Do I have to just put the 200 URLs in a string array and refer to them one by one in my webview ?

I'd much rather do it in XML, is there a way to refer to the URL string resources just by some sort of index position number ?
Remember I need to traverse the list of URLs , Showing just one resource is not a problem, I don't know how to go "next" and "previous"...
Only thing I can think is 200 if-else statements and blocks that will surely kill the performance of my app.

Any other way to do this ?

I'd appreciate a short example :-)
Thank you !